# Should I put a semicolon after ES7 decorators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

Jetbrains Webstorm keeps showing "*Unterminated statement*" for the code below.

```
@connect(props)
class NavBar extends Component {...}
```

But the message vanishes as I put a semicolon right after the decorator. I was just wondering if I have to put a semicolon after the decorators.

```
@connect(props);
class NavBar extends Component {...}
```

Comment: I would not, especially if they decorate a declaration that doesn't use semicolons on its own.

Comment: I suspect Webstorm doesn't know about decorators, so it thinks those are function calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not. According to the [draft grammar](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators#grammar), decorators are *expressions* that are part of a method or class definition. They are no statements, and must not end in semicolons.

Imo, using semicolons there would visually separate the decorator from the decoratee, which looks odd - especially if not even the decorated value ends in a semicolon. Looks like WebStorm just doesn't understand decorator syntax yet.